# Setting hp printer copy to best mode

Tags: linux, printer

I want to set the printer default photostat setting to best instead of normal. Is it possible to do so in HP Deskjet 3830 printer in linux.

Answer (score 0):

To set a printer's defaults, go to Devices and Printers. Right-click the printer and select Printer Properties. Now click the Advanced tab and then the Printing Defaults button. Set the printer up the way you want it in that window and click OK.

Now click the General tab, the Printing Preferences button and check the settings there. They should be the same as set in Printing Defaults, but if they're not, set them here as well.

The printer will now default to the new settings. Mote that, if you print via a server, these settings need to be made on that server.

If you want to set the copy quality instead of the print quality, go through the printer's front panel menu settings, especially the Settings icon. It may be possible to do it from there, but the manuals I can find do not give any information about it. They do imply that things like scan resolution have to be set from the PC, but copies are normally made without the PC.

If Copy settings can not be set on the printer, you can always copy via the PC. Software like [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) will photocopy by scanning a page and printing it at the settings you require. It keeps the last used settings.

Comment: Thanks but I am using linux not windows